# Is there a way to select an option from dropdown other than using 'Select' class in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to select an option from drop down other than using 'Select' class in Selenium?

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML and your code trial please?

Comment: Yes. Do exactly like a user would do. Press the combo box, find and select the value by clicking on it.

Comment: This is one of the interview question faced

Comment: You should provide more info with question actually what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The other way is, click on the dropdown menu and select the option from the dropdown using click method as below:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<Xpath of dropdown element>"));     // To find the dropdown web element
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<Xpath of dropdown Options"));    // To find the dropdown options
ele.click();      // To click on the dropdown element
options.get(<index>).click();      //To click on the option..
```